# Date to local time kotlin

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin

I have a date object with

> "Sun Apr 26 11:44:00 GMT+03:00 2020"

I tried to format it but it will always ignore the timezone "+3:00" and show the hour without changing it

what I have tried :

```
   val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)
    return sdf.format(this)
```

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: The first question has to be why are you using the old Java date api? Especially in Kotlin. The next thing to point out is that `Date` is **milliseconds since the epoch UTC** - there is no time zone!! The time zone you are seeing is the result of calling `toString` which will use the system default time zone. Basically, this question doesn’t make a huge amount of sense...

Comment: @sweeper I want to format the time but somehow if I got +2GMT or +3GMT I doesn't seem to effect the result in hours

Comment: Do you really want to just format that datetime differently or do you want to convert it to another zone or offset?

Comment: @deHaar I want to use the offset +3 or +2  to get the hours right

Comment: Then you should really go with `java.time` (or the backport if you are supporting API levels below 26) and use an `OffsetDateTime` or even a `ZonedDateTime` as @kaustubhpatange suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't exactly understand your question but I guess you meant you need DateTime related to a particular zone. In kotlin we've `ZonedDateTime` class

```kotlin
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.FormatStyle

val londonZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
val londonCurrentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(londonZone)
println(londonCurrentDateTime) // Output:  2018-01-25T07:41:02.296Z[Europe/London]
val londonDateAndTime = londonCurrentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.MEDIUM))
println(londonDateAndTime) // Output: Thursday, January 25, 2018 7:40:34 AM
```

You also might need to take a look at `LocalDateTime` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to parse a datetime `String` with the given pattern and then convert the result to a different offset, you can go like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // provide the source String
    val datetime = "Sun Apr 26 11:44:00 GMT+03:00 2020"
    // provide a pattern for parsing
    val parsePattern = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss O yyyy";
    // parse the String to an OffsetDateTime
    val parsedOffsetDateTime = java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(
                                datetime,
                                java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(parsePattern))
    // print the result using the default format
    println(parsedOffsetDateTime)

    // then get the same moment in time at a different offset
    val adjustedOffsetDateTime = parsedOffsetDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(
                                    java.time.ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"))
    // and print that, too, in order to see the difference
    println(adjustedOffsetDateTime)
}
```

which produces the output

```
2020-04-26T11:44+03:00
2020-04-26T10:44+02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The format string depends on which `SimpleDateFormat` you use:

- If using [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) with API Level 24+, the format string needs to be:
  `"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XXX yyyy"`
- If using [`android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat), the format string needs to be:
  `"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO yyyy"`.

*Demo (in plain Java)*

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));

Date date = new Date(1587890640000L); // date object with "Sun Apr 26 11:44:00 GMT+03:00 2020"

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XXX yyyy", Locale.US);
String dateString = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("Formatted  : " + dateString);

Date parsed = sdf.parse(dateString);
System.out.println("Parsed back: " + parsed);
System.out.println("Millis since Epoch: " + parsed.getTime());
```

*Output*

```
Formatted  : Sun Apr 26 11:44:00 GMT+03:00 2020
Parsed back: Sun Apr 26 11:44:00 IDT 2020
Millis since Epoch: 1587890640000
```